# How to access Google Translate API

Tags: javascript, google-translate

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

      function appendResults(text) {
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        results.appendChild(document.createElement('P'));
        results.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
      }

      function makeRequest() {
        var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.get({
          'shortUrl': 'http://goo.gl/fbsS'
        });
        request.then(function(response) {
          appendResults(response.result.longUrl);
        }, function(reason) {
          console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
      }

      function init() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey('*My API key*');
        gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1').then(makeRequest);
      }
    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="results"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is the sample code from getting started page to use Google Translate API [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples). I used it exactly as instructed, and I already changed the "API key" part with my API key. Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work? Is there any other library that I need to import to this .html ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No, just a blank page

Comment: I guess that's because you don't translate anything. What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

How to get access to the Google Translate API? How to get an API Key?
**1. Sign Up for Free RapidAPI Account:**
To begin using the Google Translate API, you’ll first need to sign up for a free RapidAPI developer account. With this account, you get a universal API Key to access all APIs hosted in RapidAPI.

RapidAPI is the world’s largest API marketplace, with over 10,000 APIs and a community of over 1,000,000 developers. Our goal is to help developers find and connect to APIs to help them build amazing apps.

**2. Subscribe to Google Translate API:**
Once signed in, log in to your RapidAPI account and access the API console. Click on the “Pricing” tab and opt-in for the basic subscription that gives you 50 free API calls to Google Translate API per day.

**3. Test Your API Subscription:**
Let’s test your Google Translate API subscription. Select the “POST Translate” endpoint within the API console. The default values of parameters indicate that we are going to translate the text “Hello, world!” to Spanish (with language code ‘es’). Trigger the API, and you should see the translated text in the API response (JSON format).

So, “Hello, world!” in Spanish translates to “Hola Mundo!”.

You can also check [language translator javascript code for website](https://www.coderepublics.com/howto/how-to-google-translate.php)

Answer (score 0):

The referenced page provides an example of a Translation API call, whose core lines are:

```
// Executes an API request, and returns a Promise.
```

// The method name `language.translations.list` comes from the API discovery.

```
          return gapi.client.language.translations.list({
            q: 'hello world',
            source: 'en',
            target: 'de',
          });
```

Your sample code does not seem to include an API call.